# openxml sdk 2.0 - Font not set on vowel mutations

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using the openxml sdk 2.0 for generating some word files. My problem now is that for german vowel mutations (äöÄÖÜ) the font isn't applied.

Here's an example:
[image]

Tried it with some other fonts but even with them it's not working, the font is always set to "Calibri".

*Anyone knows some hints to get the style appended to these special german characters?*

Thanks in advice.

.

This is my Method to create the character styles:

```
public static void CreateAndAddCharacterStyle(StyleDefinitionsPart styleDefinitionsPart,
    string styleid, string stylename, string aliases = "")
{
    Styles styles = styleDefinitionsPart.Styles;

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Style style = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Style()
    {
        Type = StyleValues.Character,
        StyleId = styleid,
        CustomStyle = true
    };

    Aliases aliases1 = new Aliases() { Val = aliases };
    StyleName styleName1 = new StyleName() { Val = stylename };
    LinkedStyle linkedStyle1 = new LinkedStyle() { Val = styleid + "Para" };
    if (aliases != "")
        style.Append(aliases1);
    style.Append(styleName1);
    style.Append(linkedStyle1);

    StyleRunProperties styleRunProperties1 = new StyleRunProperties();

    if (styleid == "textfett")
    {
        RunFonts font1 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Gotham Narrow Medium" };
        styleRunProperties1.Append(font1);
    }
    else
    {
        RunFonts font1 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Gotham Narrow Light" };
        styleRunProperties1.Append(font1);
    }

    style.Append(styleRunProperties1);

    styles.Append(style);
}
```

and my code for writing text:

```
List<Run> runs = new List<Run>();

Run r = new Run(new Text(node.Attributes["titel"].InnerText) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
r.RunProperties = new RunProperties();
r.RunProperties.RunStyle = new RunStyle();
r.RunProperties.RunStyle.Val = "textfett";
runs.Add(r);

r = new Run(new Break());
runs.Add(r);

foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node2 in node.ChildNodes)
{
    if (node2.Name == "info")
    {
        r = new Run(new Text(node2.Attributes["name"].InnerText + ":") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
        r.RunProperties = new RunProperties();
        r.RunProperties.RunStyle = new RunStyle();
        r.RunProperties.RunStyle.Val = "textfett";
        runs.Add(r);

        r = new Run(new Text(" " + node2.InnerText + " ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
        r.RunProperties = new RunProperties();
        r.RunProperties.RunStyle = new RunStyle();
        r.RunProperties.RunStyle.Val = "textnormal";
        runs.Add(r);
    }
    if (node2.Name == "ende")
    {
        //r = new Run(new Break());
        //runs.Add(r);

        r = new Run(new Text(node2.InnerText) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
        r.RunProperties = new RunProperties();
        r.RunProperties.RunStyle = new RunStyle();
        r.RunProperties.RunStyle.Val = "textnormal";
        runs.Add(r);
    }
}

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
foreach (Run run in runs)
{
    p.AppendChild<Run>(run);
}
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with French accented chars.

You need to set these properties for the font to be applied to accented characters. For instance :

```
RunFonts font = new RunFonts();
font.Ascii = font.HighAnsi = font.ComplexScript = @"Calibri";
```

So for modify your code as the following :

```
    RunFonts font1 = new RunFonts() { 
        Ascii = "Gotham Narrow Medium", 
        HighAnsi = "Gotham Narrow Medium", 
        ComplexScript = "Gotham Narrow Medium" };
```