# Set RunFonts for non-English characters in OpenXML

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

Consider the following snippet of code. When I print this text out to a word document, all my "åäö" characters get the default font, "Calibri (Body)", while the rest of the text get my font of choice, "Century". Why would be the best way to make OpenXml accept any non-English characters in general, or ones from a certain language in particular?

```
//Creation of Documents and a paragraph to work with

var runFontCentury = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Century" };
var size12 = new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("24") };
Run run = new Run() 
run.AppendChild(new Text("non-english åäö"));

//Appending to paragraph and printing out as a word document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402904/openxml-sdk-2-0-font-not-set-on-vowel-mutations) question.

The solution is simply to add more character sets. Most, if not all, European characters can be found in the HighAnsi character set. I also added one more set for good measure.

Solution thus:

```
var runFontCentury = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Century", HighAnsi = "Century", ComplexScript = "Century", };
```